# php how to reload "require" include file after submit in self submitting form

Tags: php, require

I am making a self processing php form. I have a header.inc and footer.inc both called with a require statement. My problem lies in my header uses a $title variable which I would like to update after post. Currently my variable is changing and I can echo it in my response (thank you) page, but the header does not reload to reflect the change.

I understand I could call the title in my main PHP file, but I was hoping to find a way to reload the require(header.inc) file and continue processing the form.

```
<?php

$title       = "XX";
$title2      = "Form";
$thisScript  = htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
require("htmlHead.inc");

function changeTitle()
{
$GLOBALS['title2'] = "Results";
}
changeTitle();

if (!isset($_POST['submit']))
{
echo <<<FORMDOC1
<form action="$thisScript" method="post" action=" " 
onSubmit="window.location.reload()">

 FORMDOC1;

 else
 {
  //random code
 }
 require("htmlFoot.inc");
 ?>
```

header.inc file in question:

```
 <?php
 echo "<!doctype html> <!-- Author:       $author -->\n";
 echo "<html lang=\"en\"><!-- Date Written: $dateWritten -->\n";
 echo "<head>          <!-- Description:  $description -->\n";
 echo "\t<title>$title</title>\n";
 echo "\t<title>$title2</title>\n";
 echo "\t<meta charset=\"utf-8\" />\n"; 
 echo "\t<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"css.css\" />\n";
 echo "</head>\n";
 echo "<body>\n";
 echo "<div id=\"wrapper\">\n";
 echo "<h1>$title</h1>\n";
 echo "<h2>$title2</h2>\n";
 ?>
```

Comment: Post your code, not just an explanation of what you need.

Comment: @brianphelps can you edit your question to add the code ? make sure to format it for readability. you might also find this helpful on how to ask good questions on SO https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: sorry about that I have never posted to this site before, some irrelevant data has been removed. but you can see my function changeTitle to change the title of the response page but it does not update the header, probably due to it not reloading

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the title after including the header. Therefore, the value hasn't changed yet at the time php has output the header content.

Try following this general structure

```
if(isset($_POST['submit')) {
  //process the form
  include('header.inc');
  //display confirmation

}
else {
  include('header.inc');
  //display the form
}

include('footer.inc');
```

Comment: Genus! You are a life saver!